# Casting an implementation of Interface B to and implementation of Interface A

Tags: c#, types, interface, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to get code below running. I want to cast an object of class A to an object of class B, buit i get an error. In theory, the A is a part of B, so I can't see, why this won't work.

I know, that this cast does mean losing some data, but that is exactly what I want.
Is there any way to get this running?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new B();
        var a = (A)b; //Error: Cannot convert type
    }
}

public interface IA{}

public interface IB : IA{}

public class A : IA{}

public class B : IB{}
```

Comment: it is `IA` that is part of `B`, not `A`. Change to `var a = (IA)b;`

Comment: FYI: "_I know, that this cast does mean losing some data_". With respect to reference types (i.e. objects; **not** value types like _int_, _float_, etc.), casting normally does not incur a loss of data. Exception to this are classes which implement (explicit/implicit) conversion operators whose custom implementation would result in a "loss of data" (so to speak)...

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, B is not of type A and vice versa:

[image]

It's impossible to cast B to A. You only can cast to IB or IA types.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in multiple ways, one being the way Gilad Green stated in his answer, or by also implementing a conversion method:

```
        public static implicit operator A(B b)
        {
            //your code to convert from B to A
        }

        public static implicit operator B(A a)
        {
            //your code to convert from A to B
        }
```

Since B implements both IA and IB you cannot directly cast to and from one another unless you implement something like the code snippet in this answer.

Comment: Well yes, that's possible. But I reckon that's more an advanced programming technique than a lesson in object inheritance.

Comment: I cant argue with that, Alpha75 basicly showed nicely in his answer the problem of why he couldnt cast from one to another, i merely provided (a somewhat more advanced) way of getting the programmabillity which he requested :)